# How to split payout on Android Market?

Tags: android, google-play

Me and my friend are considering developing together on Android platform. I would like to know whether there is a way to split payouts into two shares and send them to two different bank accounts.

1. Is there a better way for doing that than forming a company or
   registering one of our bank account and split it into two after
   every payouts?
2. How would you avoid trust issues?

I tried to find support email address on the Android Developers page, but I didn't succeed (I'm not a registered developer yet).

Comment: This really isn't a SO question but you should really set up a company. These questions are more legal based!

Comment: If you trust your fiend and he trust you, one can receive the payments and the split it. If either of you don't trust each other, don't make business together.. :)

Comment: I expected this answer and I can see the truth in it. :) Just better be sure...

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built in way to split the revenue. The money made from sales can be transferred to only one bank account at the time.